# Question about orthogonality principle

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Orthogonality principle states the following:

let $V$ and $W$ be any random variables then for any function $f(W)$
\begin{align}
E[(V-E[V|W])f(W)]=0
\end{align}

My question is wether the following is also true let let $g(V,W)$ be some function of $V,W$ then for any $f(W)$ we have that 
\begin{align}
E \left[ \left(g(V,W)-E[g(V,W)|W]\right) f(W) \right]=0
\end{align}

I strongly believe this is true and a simple substitution into the fist equation should prove it. But I would like confirmation from you guys.

Comment: ?? Use the property you know for the random variable $\mathbf V=g(V,W)$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity

$$\mathbb{E}[(g(V,W)-\mathbb{E}(g(V,W) \mid W)) f(W)]=0$$

is a direct consequence of the tower property. *Indeed:* Conditioning on $\sigma(W)$ yields

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}[(g(V,W)-\mathbb{E}(g(V,W) \mid W)) f(W)) &= \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \mathbb{E} \big[ (g(V,W)-\mathbb{E}(g(V,W) \mid W)) f(W)) \mid W \big] \bigg] \\ &\stackrel{\ast}{=} \mathbb{E} \bigg[ f(W) \underbrace{[\mathbb{E}(g(V,W) \mid W)-\mathbb{E}(g(V,W) \mid W)]}_{0} \bigg] \\ &= 0. \end{align*}$$

In $(\ast)$ we used that $f(W)$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(W)$, and that we can therefore pull it outside the conditional expectation.